# dictionary loop hw - Python

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7

Part of my hw assignment requires me to write a function which takes a dictionary with keys being strings of numbers, such as 1111, 3333, etc., and definitions also being strings of numbers, and check which keys have the most amount of definitions in common. I'm assuming this needs to be done by looping through a dictionary, and this is the code I have so far:

```
def most_friends_common(id, all_users):
    frds_common = 0
    friends_of_id = set()
    friends_of_key = set()
    friends_list = []
    print "Most friends in common:"
    for friends in all_users(id):
        friends_of_id = friends_of_id.add(friends)
    for key in all_users:
        for value in key:
            friends_of_key = friends_of_key.add(value)
            if len(friends_of_key & friends_of_id) >= frds_common:
                frds_common = len(friends_of_key & friends_of_id)
                friends_list.append(value)
    print "%s: %s" %(id, str(friends_list))
```

id being a string of any 4 digit number, and all_users being the dictionary. 
I'm just wondering why it's not working and what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `all_users(id)` with `all_users[id]`?

Comment: Whoops. Silly mistake, but yeah, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To find a user that has the most friends in common with the given user specified by its user id:

```
def most_friends_common(user_id, all_users):
    def nfriends_common(id, friends=set(all_users[user_id])):
        return len(friends.intersection(all_users[id])) if id != user_id else -1
    return max(all_users, key=nfriends_common)
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/Zv7Isq)

```
print(most_friends_common('4444', {
            '1111': ['2222', '3333'], # 1111 has 2222, 3333 friends
            '2222': ['1111'],
            '3333': ['1111', '4444', '5555'],
            '4444': ['1111', '2222', '3333'],
            '5555': []}))
# -> 1111
```